# Disable breadcrumb navigation in KDE

Tags: kde, file-opening

I want to copy the file path from a file open dialog, but can't because of breadcrumb-style navigation.  There's no option in the dialog itself to switch between breadcrumb and address bar.

I want to disable the breadcrumbs system wide so that the file browser, open dialogs, etc., all use the address bar.

This is KDE on Red Hat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on the location bar or press Ctrl-L it will become editable. In Dolphin you can also press F6. This is on KDE 4.14, but as far as I remember it worked in the earlier versions too.

Comment: This doesn't work, at least not with all dialogs, only some.  Is there any way to force it system-wide?

Comment: Every toolkit has its own file dialog implementation, kde has one, qt, gtk, tk and others have their own. If you stick to kde applications your experience should be consistent. And no, there is no easy way to force it system-wide.

Comment: >can't force system wide...

Was afraid of that. Thanks @contemplator